# CKEditor4 is not working on old PHP Version

Tags: ckeditor

I am using CKEditor 4 built in version with skin mooncolor. It's working fine with PHP 7 but it is not working on PHP 5.6. Is it recommended to upgrade PHP to work CKEditor4?

Comment: What kind of PHP framework are you using? CKeditor is Javascript so i guess you are talking about a PHP framework implementation of CKeditor??

Answer (score 0):

I am using codeigniter PHP framework. I have used CKEditor library which is for PHP. I have taken built in version